# How can I assert two different values for two different objects with 'assert_difference'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following test below:

```
it 'create action: a user replies to a post for the first time' do
  login_as user

  # ActionMailer goes up by two because a user who created a topic has an accompanying post.
  # One email for post creation, another for post replies.
  assert_difference(['Post.count', 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size'], 2) do
    post :create, topic_id: topic.id, post: { body: 'Creating a post for the first time.' }
  end
  email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

  email.first.to.must_equal [user.email]
  email.subject.must_equal 'Post successfully created'
  must_redirect_to topic_path(topic.id)

  email.last.to.must_equal [user.email]
  email.subject.must_equal 'Post reply sent'
  must_redirect_to topic_path(topic.id)
end
```

The test above breaks because of the `assert_difference` block in the code. To make this test pass I need for Post.count to increment by 1 and then have `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` to increment by 2. That scenario will make the test pass. I've tried to rewrite the code into this second type of test.

```
it 'create action: a user replies to a post for the first time' do
  login_as user

  assert_difference('Post.count', 1) do
    post :create, topic_id: topic.id, post: { body: 'Creating a post for the first time.' }
  end

  # ActionMailer goes up by two because a user who created a topic has an accompanying post.
  # One email for post creation, another for post reply.
  assert_difference('ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size', 2) do
    post :create, topic_id: topic.id, post: { body: 'Creating a post for the first time.' }
  end

  email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

  email.first.to.must_equal [user.email]
  email.subject.must_equal 'Post successfully created'
  must_redirect_to topic_path(topic.id)

  email.last.to.must_equal [user.email]
  email.subject.must_equal 'Post reply sent'
  must_redirect_to topic_path(topic.id)
end
```

This second iteration is close to what I want but not quite. The problem with this code is that it will create a post object twice due to the create calls in the `assert_difference` block. I've looked at the `assert_difference` code in the rails api guide and api docks found here ([assert_difference API dock](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions/assert_difference) but this is not what I need. I need something like this:

```
assert_difference ['Post.count','ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size'], 1,2 do
   #create a post
end
```

Is there a way to implement that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can nest them, like this:

```
assert_difference("Post.count", 1) do
  assert_difference("ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size", 2) do
    # Create a post
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 10):

You can also pass a hash of Procs to the `assert_difference` method, which I believe would be the recommended way.

```rb
assert_difference ->{ Post.count } => 1, ->{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size } => 2 do
  # create post
end
```

You can check another example in the docs [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_difference)

Comment: A Hash of strings is also permitted and the output seems to be more readable if an assertion fails. You can do:
`assert_difference('Post.count' => 1, 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size' => 2) do ... end`